# custom number format: Show "ok" if cell is not empty

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a column I have different values. Some are numbers, numbers + letters, some numbers have a leading 0 (Zero).
Therefore I formatted the column as text.

With help of the number format I want to display a "ok" instead of the value in the cell, if the cell has a value.
I tried to apply a trick from here: https://trumpexcel.com/excel-custom-number-formatting/

```
[>1]"Ok";""
```

But then the values don't have the leading Zero in the beginning any more.
Newly added values do also loose the leading Zero.
**Is there a way to write the number format to show "ok" and leave the values as they are** (and with a leading zero)?

[image]

Here I apllied the `[>1]"Ok";""`
and lost not only the leading zero but the whole number got messed up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, but need a different approach in the number formatting string.

The example given addresses numerical values and if >1, places the "OK" you show. It only works because Excel is no longer treating them as text. And that's something you required Excel to stop doing by changing the format.

There are two ways to use the number formatting strings. One is the usual one, and the other is the above. I won't talk much about the one above as you aren't asking for an explanation of it. Of course, enter a new question and...

In the usual use, there are four parts to a full formatting string. The first is how to format positive numbers, the second, negative numbers, the third, zeros, and the fourth, text.

You need to use the fourth parameter in the usual string. I shall show what you need there using simple stuff for the first three since you don't seem to need them.

So, a string like:  `0;-0;0;"OK"`  will give the result you desire. It will DISPLAY the "OK" but will not change the value in the cell in any way. Since it is still treated as text by Excel, it retains any leading zeros and other features, and will not be shortened (you may not have noticed it, but in additions to the other unhappy things Excel did, it also shortened your original values to the first 15 significant digits of each). Since it is not considered as a number, Excel will also not change the display to the scientific notation you seem to dislike as much as I do.

That will take care of what is directly asked. By the way, once Excel does these things, like dropping the leading zeros and shortening the values to 15 significant digits, they are permanent. You cannot get Excel to give them back. If you imported them, you can import them anew, but if you hand entered them, you're at an end. You will have to hand enter them again.

Comment: 0;-0;0;"OK" will only return an "ok" for values which contain a letter not for only numbers.  "ok";0;0;"ok" will return a ok for both, but then, when entering a leading zero, it gets lost anyway.